# Chicagoboss make error for lager

Tags: chicagoboss, lager

I am porting my web application developed in Chicagoboss from my mac to ubuntu. But when I run make on ubuntu I get the following error:

ERROR: pre_compile failed while processing /home/myname/myapp_priv: {'EXIT',{undef,[{lager,start,[],[]},
    {boss_rebar,compile,4,
                            [{file,"../ChicagoBoss-0.8.12/priv/rebar/boss_rebar.erl"},
                             {line,97}]},
                {boss_plugin,pre_compile,2,
                             [{file,"priv/rebar/boss_plugin.erl"},{line,105}]},
                {rebar_core,run_modules,4,[]},
                {rebar_core,execute,5,[]},
                {rebar_core,process_dir1,6,[]},
                {rebar_core,process_commands,2,[]},
                {rebar,main,1,[]}]}}
make: *** [all] Error 1

Am I missing something? Thanking all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates, that lager parse transforms are not present while compiling. Lager does not define functions like `lager:info` or `lager:error` directly. During compilation, it changes those calls adding line number and other useful things.

Your problem can be usually solved by moving lager before any other dependency in `./deps/boss/rebar.config` or adding it as a dependency directly to your application in `./rebar.config`.